# How do I style the dropdown for a text input with a "list" attribute?

Tags: css, html

I've created a text input with a "list" attribute and I'm wondering if there is a way to style the default dropdown arrow.

```
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" list="subjects" placeholder="Subject">
<datalist id="subjects">
    <option value="General Question"></option>
    <option value="Technical Support"></option>
    <option value="Billing Question"></option>
    <option value="Report a Bug"></option>
</datalist>
```

Here's the result.
[image]

Comment: I suspect that the answer will be the same as - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript?rq=1

Comment: yes, you can hide (appearance:none;) and replace with a image ( background: url(your path) no-repeat right top; )

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried that in Chrome but it didn't work

Comment: If you tried something and it didn't work you should show us that...perhaps you made a mistake. Otherwise your question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your CSS to remove and add the arrow/indicator from the input in chrome.

```
//Remove Native Arrow
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}

//Add Image Arrow
input[list]{
   background:url("//www.bricklink.com/3D/down.png") no-repeat right 1px; // Adjust your needs
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/bsq769v9/2/)**

Comment: Yes, Luis. That's exactly right! Thank you. Can you edit your answer to include `input[list]{background:url("down_arrow.png") no-repeat right 1px}`. That way instead of just hiding the arrow you're replacing it. Then I'll give the you correct answer.